# Is there a way to use the windows scheduled task to kick off a url or a exe on a schedule

Tags: azure, cron, scheduled-tasks

Using a Windows Azure VM, can I kick off a Job or call an exe or url every minute?
Is there a way to do that in windows task scheduler in an Azure VM?

Is there a better way to do a CRON type operation in Azure?

Thanks for your help!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically schedule tasks to run on Windows Azure VM's using the Task Scheduler.  This can be done my providing a startup task to your Role and using the "at" command to schedule tasks with Task Scheduler.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565

Comment: how can I get it to run every minute?

Comment: Just found this schtasks command: schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "Task Name" /tr c:\temp\filename.exe

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as getting a task to run on Windows locally.  The only difference is that you need to upload the exe as a part of your project (set it to Content and Copy Local - Copy Always) and then you can use an method you like.  Setting up a startup task to run the exe is easiest and have the exe sleep and wake up every minute or so to execute.

Comment: how can I get it to run every minute?